# Can't bind to 'spiedTags' since it isn't a known property of 'div' Angular angular-scroll-spy

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-material

got an error when implementing 'angular-scroll-spy' !

NG8002: Can't bind to 'spiedTags' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
this is .html file

```
<div *ngIf="candidate_output; else contentLoading;" id="parentDiv" scrollSpy [spiedTags]="['DIV']" (sectionChange)="onSectionChange($event)">
```

Comment: Can you also paste `scrollSpy` code too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create another directive for this module or for best practice you create a shared module where your can create pipes ,directive... and export the module then you import it wh